# Перестали определяться адреса по координатам (Geocoding API)

Tags: android, google-maps-api, geocoding

Сделал два приложения по определению местоположения и по запросу адреса от Google, повесил на них один ключ API. Какое-то время всё работало, потом стало приходить сообщение, причём в обоих приложениях:

> Sorry, the service is not available

Все лимиты пустые.

Может, у Google были какие то изменения за последние два месяца, и он что-то отключил?

При попытке подключить Geocoding API пишет в консоли:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

---

Решено: просто я забыл, что отключил Geocoding API в консоли, подключил обратно, перезагрузил аппарат — всё заработало.

Comment: Вопрос нужно удалить или написать сами же напишите к нему ответ и отметьте как решенный чтоб он не маячил в поиске как неотвеченный

Comment: два дня сказали ждать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: просто я забыл что отключил Geocoding API в консоле, подключил обратно, перезагрузил аппарат все заработало.